# Bizarre audio behavior with IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am trying to embed HTML5 Audio into a web project to play in the background when certain events are triggered.

What's strange is, that Internet Explorer apparently won't load audio from one of my web domains. To demonstrate this, I made 4 identical copies of a recording, 2 of which I put in `sandbox.g-liu.com` (a subdomain), and 2 of which I put in `g-liu.com` (no subdomain). The code is below. Note that I am using absolute URLs, so that this code will not cause 404 no matter where it is put.

```
<audio id="asmpg" controls>
        <source src="http://sandbox.g-liu.com/src/cat.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
        <source src="http://sandbox.g-liu.com/src/cat.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
        No audio support.
</audio>

<h2>Audio MP3/OGG from other subdomain</h2>

<audio id="admpg" controls>
        <source type="audio/mpeg" src="http://g-liu.com/files/cat.mp3" />
        <source type="audio/ogg" src="http://g-liu.com/files/cat.ogg" />
</audio>
```

JS FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/2xrUK/

**Opera, Firefox, Chrome**: loads both audio elements.

**Safari**: Not tested. Don't own a Mac.

**Internet Explorer 11**: loads the first one `#asmpg` fine, but cannot load the audio from `g-liu.com`. In the console, I get the message,

`MEDIA12899: AUDIO/VIDEO: Unknown MIME type.`

The other browsers do not have this issue, and can play the audio fine. At this point, it is beyond me why IE cannot retrieve the audio from `g-liu.com`. It tells me that it's encountering an unknown MIME Type but I did specify it in the `source` tag. Perhaps it's the way that the data is sent to the web page?

*(Side note: For debugging purposes, this is a simplification of what I'm trying to do. In actual development, I am loading the audio asynchronously, and having audio play/pause when user clicks a button.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup the server to send the files with correct MIME type.

You can use http://simonecarletti.com/tools/http-checker to test. Look for "Content-type".

http://g-liu.com/files/cat.mp3 says "application/octet-stream". Should be "audio/mpeg".

Also in your example you write audio/mp3 and audio/mpeg. They should both be audio/mpeg.

You can add the following in a .htaccess file in the website root to change Apache setup :

```
AddType audio/mpeg .mp3
```

The problem is your server settings. Not IE11 or your code.

Comment: Thank you so much, it turns out that I had a line in HTACCESS: `AddType application/octet-stream` which would encourage the browser to download instead of play the file in-line. Got rid of that, and the  default MIME TYPE (with no `AddType` specified) looks to be `audio/mpeg`.

**EDIT**: `audio/mp3` was a typo, my apologies.